# What are the upsides to having the spell-like ability version of a spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bloodline, orc

The question is specifically about the [Orc Bloodine](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/orc-bloodline). At the final level, you get this:

> Warlord Reborn (Su): At 20th level, you become a true orc warlord of
>   legend. You gain immunity to fire and DR 5/—. Once per day, you can
>   cast transformation as a spell-like ability using your sorcerer level
>   as your caster level.

I can already cast transformation at that point, and plenty of times at that. Is the spell-like ability supposed to be some kind of reward? It doesn't feel like it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A [spell-like ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-)'s advantages over a spell lie primarily in its lack of [components](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components). It require none. So while the warlord reborn may already be able to cast the spell *transformation* repeatedly, being able employ the spell's effect as a spell-like ability, too, can be an advantage in the right circumstances. As [gatherer818](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/14948/gatherer818) points out, some of those circumstances include

> while grappled or pinned, or while deafened or emotive blocked, in a zone of silence, with your hands tied behind your back, gagged, hands cut off, tongue cut out, no potions, enemy with a readied action to sunder your potion if you pull it out...

(All of which, I assume, the GM has, at some time or another, inflicted upon gatherer818's hapless characters. My sympathies are with Handless Bob and Tongueless Joe.)

So, instead of casting the spell and all the hassle that goes with that, a warlord reborn merely stares into space for a standard action (provoking attacks of opportunity), and the effect of the spell [*transformation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transformation) occurs.

To emphasize futher, likely the most immediately noticeable effect of having the spell *transformation* as a spell-like ability is that the warlord reborn is spared the expense of the *potion of [bull's strength](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bull-s-strength)* that's normally consumed as a material component when the spell is cast.

Comment: Huh, ok. That makes sense.Thank you! This all said, for a level 20 power,it's still kind of "meh" to me. Would of loved to be bale to cast during transformation or something else that feels strong.

Comment: While the ability itself is supernatural, it does grant a spell-like ability.

Comment: @Thisisstackoverflow It's a shame *Pathfinder* characters don't get a feat at level 20. Were they to, the orc could then totally take [Quicken Spell-like Ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/quicken-spell-like-ability) (*transformation*), but, yes, as it stands it's a little dumb except for the 300 gp savings for each use.

Comment: The *transformation* still doesn't take a 6th level slot, can be used while grappled or pinned, or while deafened or *emotive block*ed, in a zone of silence, with your hands tied behind your back, gagged, hands cut off, tongue cut out, no potions, enemy with a readied action to sunder your potion if you pull it out...  also, if you're a Sorcerer archetype that trades your sixth level bloodline spell (or gets [two options](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo---sorcerer-archetypes/crossblooded) at sixth level), you might not have *transformation* on your list.

Comment: Granted, it doesnt help you much in terms of combat power but it effectively enables you to escape any normal restraints which IS indeed a powerful ability.

Answer (score 2):

It's an extra spell slot.

Even if you'd just use a potion, potions can get too expensive when you need higher caster levels but Spell Like Abilities (SLA) have their caster level increase along with your hit die.

Recharge Innate Magic is a spell that restores all spell like abilities which is great as you can use a CL1 scroll to recover an SLA with an effective caster level of whatever your HD is.

Some spells you'd use so much you'd like to have them as scrolls but the spell in question is a Swift action or Immediate action cast so rather useless as a scroll. If the spell were as an SLA then you could use it then recharge it in between combat with a CL1 scroll of Recharge Innate Magic.

Many spells are ruined by verbal components, not just how Silence can affect so many areas but how speaking in a "strong voice" ruins any element of stealth you had.