# Can a rogue with minor/major magic talent use wizard wands without UMD

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, magic, rogue

Can a pathfinder rogue who takes the Minor Magic / Major Magic talents then be able to use Wizard wands (ie no UMD check required)?

From the below research I can not see why they could not. You can use any wand as long as the spell is on your spell list even if you can't cast it. Therefore as the minor/major magic rogue talents give you access to the Wiz/Sorc spell list I believe that you should be able to use the wizard/sorc wands. Scrolls would still require checks as per UMD or spellcasting checks.

> Minor Magic (Sp): A rogue with this talent gains the ability to cast a 0-level spell from the sorcerer/wizard spell list. This spell can be cast at will as a spell-like ability. The rogue's caster level for this ability is equal to her rogue level. The save DC for this spell is 10 + the rogue's Intelligence modifier. A rogue must have an Intelligence score of at least 10 to select this talent.
>
> Major Magic (Sp): A rogue with this talent gains the ability to cast a 1st-level spell from the sorcerer/wizard spell list once per day as a spell-like ability for every 2 rogue levels she possesses. The rogue's caster level for this ability is equal to her rogue level. The save DC for this spell is 11 + the rogue's Intelligence modifier. A rogue must have the minor magic rogue talent and an Intelligence score of at least 11 to select this talent.

As a rogue can now cast spells from the Wiz/Sorc list would it then follow normal wand activation/triggers?

> Activation: Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so casting a spell from a wand is usually a standard action that doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity. (If the spell being cast has a longer casting time than 1 action, however, it takes that long to cast the spell from a wand.) To activate a wand, a character must hold it in hand (or whatever passes for a hand, for nonhumanoid creatures) and point it in the general direction of the target or area. A wand may be used while grappling or while swallowed whole.
>
> Spell Trigger: Spell trigger activation is similar to spell completion, but it's even simpler. No gestures or spell finishing is needed, just a special knowledge of spellcasting that an appropriate character would know, and a single word that must be spoken. Spell trigger items can be used by anyone whose class can cast the corresponding spell. This is the case even for a character who can't actually cast spells, such as a 3rd-level paladin. The user must still determine what spell is stored in the item before she can activate it. Activating a spell trigger item is a standard action and does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

Some thoughts on this would be great!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. The differences between spells, extraordinary abilities, spell-like abilities, and supernatural abilities, I think, should be among the first things discussed if a new version of *Pathfinder* is published. The differences are subtle, complicated, important, and easy to overlook. A fine question. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## A [spell-like ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-) is not a spell

The [unchained rogue talents](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/rogue-talents) [Minor Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/minor-magic) and [Major Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/major-magic) only grant [spell-like abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-), not spells proper nor spell lists, and spell-like abilities *don't* interact with the spell lists except, for instance, like in these cases, to limit the spell-like abilities the rogue can pick.

[The FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9ofm) says:

> **Question:** Does a creature with a spell-like ability count as having that spell on its spell list for the purpose of activating spell completion or spell trigger items?
>
> **Answer:** No. A spell-like ability is not a spell, having a spell-like ability is not part of a class's spell list, and therefore doesn't give the creature the ability to activate spell completion or spell trigger items.

Thus a rogue without a spell list from another source must usually employ the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) to activate wands.

Comment: Awesome. Missed that part totally. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Shadow My pleasure. You can read more about spell-like abilities [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74027/8610) and [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28993/8610).